# How to capture screenshots for every test step in protractor cucumber typescript framework?

Tags: typescript, npm, protractor, cucumber

I have two questions.One is how to capture the screenshots for every test step and the second one is how to attach the respective screenshots beside my each test step in my cucumber-html-reporter.I am new to protractor so need some help.

I am using cucumber-reporter and I have placed the code which I am placed the config, hooks, reporter.ts files.Let me know where I need to make the changes.
Thank you:)

config.ts:

```
import * as path from "path";
import { browser, Config } from "protractor";
import { Reporter } from "../support/reporter";

const jsonReports = process.cwd() + "/reports/json";

export const config: Config = {
seleniumAddress: "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub",
SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,
baseUrl: "http://www.leafground.com/pages/Dropdown.html",

capabilities: {
    browserName: "chrome",
},

framework: "custom",
frameworkPath: require.resolve("protractor-cucumber-framework"),

specs: [
    "../../features/*.feature",
],

onPrepare: () => {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.manage().window().maximize();
    Reporter.createDirectory(jsonReports);
},
cucumberOpts: {
    compiler: "ts:ts-node/register",
    format: "json:./reports/json/cucumber_report.json",
    require: ["../../typeScript/stepdefinitions/*.js", "../../typeScript/support/*.js"],
    strict: true,
    tags: "(@ListOfWebelementsScenario)"
},

onComplete: () => {
    Reporter.createHTMLReport();
},
      };
```

hooks.ts:

```
const { BeforeAll, After, AfterAll, Status } = require("cucumber");
import * as fs from "fs";
import { browser } from "protractor";
import { config } from "../config/config";

BeforeAll({timeout: 100 * 1000}, async () => {
await browser.get(config.baseUrl);
});

 After(async function(scenario) {
 if (scenario.result.status === Status.FAILED) {
    // screenShot is a base-64 encoded PNG
     const screenShot = await browser.takeScreenshot();
     this.attach(screenShot, "image/png");
    }
 });

 AfterAll({timeout: 100 * 1000}, async () => {
 await browser.quit();
  });
```

reporter.ts:

```
import * as reporter from "cucumber-html-reporter";
import * as fs from "fs";
import * as mkdirp from "mkdirp";
import * as path from "path";
const jsonReports = path.join(process.cwd(), "/reports/json");
const htmlReports = path.join(process.cwd(), "/reports/html");
const targetJson = jsonReports + "/cucumber_report.json";

const cucumberReporterOptions = {
jsonFile: targetJson,
output: htmlReports + "/cucumber_reporter.html",
reportSuiteAsScenarios: true,
theme: "bootstrap",
};

export class Reporter {

public static createDirectory(dir: string) {
    if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
        mkdirp.sync(dir);
    }
   }

  public static createHTMLReport() {
    try {
        reporter.generate(cucumberReporterOptions); // invoke cucumber- 
    html-reporter
    } catch (err) {
        if (err) {
            throw new Error("Failed to save cucumber test results to json 
        file.");
          }
       }
     }
     }
```

Comment: I use protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter for same purpose

Comment: Could you please send me your git repo

Comment: It is pretty much simple to implement! https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter

Comment: How can you take screenshot after EACH step in test with protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter? By "each step" I understand every action in test. Every click etc.